# How to to Luke support lucene 4.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, lucene, luke

As the title suggests i am trying to view lucene indexes using luke but the current version of luke does not support lucene 4.1. Does anybody know how to update luke. I googled and found a file that is supposed to the update for luke. But don’t know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Luke](https://code.google.com/p/luke/) is normally a little bit behind. At the moment of writing, current Lucene version is 4.1 and Luke is at 4.0.0-ALPHA.

As this is purely voluntary/community project, you are more than welcome to join and get it out sooner ;-)